# Add a <tr> every odd/even number of <tr>

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngfor

Currently I have this loop:

```
<tr *ngFor="let n of [42, 42, 43, 43, 1, 2, 3]; let i = index">
    <td class="branch">Branch</td>
    <td class="date">Date</td>
    <td class="account">Account {{n}} - Account Name</td>

    <td class="debit" *ngIf="i % 2 == 0">100000</td>
    <td class="credit" *ngIf="i % 2 == 0">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="debit" *ngIf="i % 2 == 1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="credit" *ngIf="i % 2 == 1">100000</td>
</tr>
```

then, I want to add below code every even number of rows.

```
<tr>
    <td class="description" colspan="5" >Trasaction detail here...</td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that I cannot access the variable `i` in the above loop. How can solve this?

**EDIT**
The result should be like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <td class="branch">Branch</td>
      <td class="date">Date</td>
      <td class="account">Account  - Account Name</td>
      <td class="debit">100000</td>
      <td class="credit">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="branch">Branch</td>
      <td class="date">Date</td>
      <td class="account">Account  - Account Name</td>
      <td class="debit">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="credit">100000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="description" colspan="5" >Trasaction detail here...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="branch">Branch</td>
      <td class="date">Date</td>
      <td class="account">Account  - Account Name</td>
      <td class="debit">30000</td>
      <td class="credit">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="branch">Branch</td>
      <td class="date">Date</td>
      <td class="account">Account  - Account Name</td>
      <td class="debit">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="credit">30000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="description" colspan="5" >Trasaction 2 detail here...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand. You want to put a <tr> inside another <tr> ? Can you post an example output you want?

Comment: @Paul Added the output that I want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<table>
  <ng-template ngFor let-even="even" let-odd="odd" let-n [ngForOf]="[42, 42, 43, 43, 1, 2, 3]">
    <tr>
      <td class="branch">Branch</td>
      <td class="date">Date</td>
      <td class="account">Account {{n}} - Account Name</td>

      <td class="debit" *ngIf="even">100000</td>
      <td class="credit" *ngIf="even">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="debit" *ngIf="odd">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="credit" *ngIf="odd">100000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="odd">
      <td class="description" colspan="5" >Trasaction detail here...</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</table>
```